# Passing parameter back to the same PHP file

Tags: php

I have two PHP files: A.php and B.php. A passes `$id` to B using POST and B can get `$id` the first time but I need to jump back to B again using `Header`. This time the parameter gets lost.

How can I pass the parameter when I use `Header` to jump back?

Comment: you be in details as to what you are trying to achieve alongwith some code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must Use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_POST` so it will work in both case . and when you use header to jump back again use query string with same name.

Comment: Or you $_POST and then $_GET, because those are the actions. $_REQUEST is fine but if you want to be sure about the verb you shouldn't use it

Answer (score 0):

you can pass id variable in the query string when you redirect.